# Mac : python script is disabled after long running

Tags: python, macos, system

I developed a python script, it needs about 36hrs to finish the job.

A print() command is added in my script to report the status of processing every 10min so I can check if the script is running well.

Every thing was fine yesterday evening and I use `pmset noidle` in terminal to prevent mac sleeping, but this morning I found the process was somehow disabled. The print() reporter responded no more but the process is still normal running according to `htop`, which used 99% of one CPU and 0.1% MEM (is is not normal).

I thought at first that mac went to sleep and my process had trouble to recover (large data processing), that's why i tried pmset noidle. But today's result is contrary to this sleeping theory.

I come here to seek wisdom, did anyone have same trouble?
thanks

Comment: Maybe your machine simply doesn't have enough resources to digest it?

Comment: the last report from my reporter gave 99% for 3 of CPU cores (8 cores) and 44% MEM usage (32GB)

Comment: This iMac I used is deeply configured by company IT guy for security reason. The fact is if I disconnect my iMac from company's network, i can not use terminal (need login, but my login is not working).

Comment: I don't know why, but I solve my problem by play nyan cat on youtube......